# gpio directory is missing

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, gpio, beagleboneblack

[screen from class directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lenZ.png)

I am beginner in embedded linux and I'm following guide https://medium.com/geekculture/understanding-the-basics-of-general-purpose-input-outputs-on-the-beaglebone-black-1568aacd67c9.
I want to access to gpio folder, but in `/sys/class/` I have no `gpio`.
I've built image by default `bitbake core-image-minimal` (yocto)
I'm testing all on BeagleBoneBlack

Comment: What you really need is to have `libgpiod` installed and then see if the tools can handle GPIO accesses. In case you don't see any GPIO controller would mean that you have not properly configured them in the Device Tree.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have told that you are a beginner so let me make it more simple,

In simple, You have to activate the GPIO_SYSFS kernel flag.

By using the command

```
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

It will open up a menu then Press `/` it will open up a search prompt, in that prompt search `GPIO_SYSFS` go to the location of it and turn it ON or 'enable' it.

Save and exit from the menuconfig menu, when you will try to save it, it will ask you about the name of the file in which you want to save these parameters, let it be `.config`

Now what is happening here is that your flag is being turned ON for your host machine yocto but it is not in your build yet.

you have to run another command

```
bitbake -c diffconfig virtual/kernel
```

it will return a path for a difference file, go on that path and you will probably find a difference file named `fragment.cfg` It will only contain the newly activated flags though.

Now you have to make a bb append file to append your kernel, whatever name of the kernel you have in your build, and then bitbake the image again, the newly made changes in your kernel will be in your build now

Comment: Thank you very much!
I should do it right after bitbake core-image-minimal ?

Comment: It is independent from the image recipe, it will activate the flag and rebuild the kernel, after that you do `bitbake core-image-minimal` to assemble the new kernel.

Comment: Excuse me,  I don’t understand a little bit. I should assemble the new kernel on image recipe on host machine, right (on which I built image)?

Comment: When you compile the kernel again, then run the core-image-minimal again, it will automatically finds out that the kernel has been modified and it will assembled in the image automaticall, so just do the kernel steps (menuconfig, compile) and then run core-image-minimal and flash your board

Comment: After compilation of kernel I still don't have `gpio` folder

Comment: @savinposter I did the same thing and still no gpio folder, did you happen to solve this?